# Incorporating multiple calculations for a CommCare SMS reminder

Tags: commcare

In setting the conditions to be met to send a "reminder" SMS, there is an option for "matches regular expression" regarding case properties and triggering reminder messages.

Can I use a complicated calculation statement in the "matches regular expression" box? I have multiple somewhat complex parameters that I want to all feed into my SMS trigger.

It looks like there is only space for one case property to dictate the SMS trigger, so I was wondering how to deal with a trigger that requires multiple expressions.

Answer (score 1):

This trigger system only supports one expression.

A way to incorporate multiple expressions or calculations into the SMS trigger is to store the outcome of the expression in a hidden value in a corresponding form, and then save that outcome as a case property. This single outcome saved as a property can then be the one property that triggers the SMS reminder.